# asp net core 2.1 IFormFile

Tags: asp.net-core

Как сохранить файл IFormFile HttpPostedFileBase на linux, на windows сохраняю вот так всё работает:

```
 using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, fileName), FileMode.Create))
                                    {
                                        await HttpPostedFileBase.CopyToAsync(stream);
                                    }
```

Но на linux сервере файл не сохраняется, я думаю что проблема в путях файла. Как мне указать путь (корень)\store\files

Пытался указывать следующие пути:

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME"), "store");
Path.Combine("\store");
```

Но не один из вариантов не сработал, на \store права 777

Answer (score 1):

Я написал 9 различных метов из них сработали:

```
Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
Path.Combine("/" + Path.Combine(filePath.ToArray())
@"/", "store", "InstituteFiles"
```

Вывод: Если вам нужно указать путь относительно корня используйте обратный слеш '\' в начале пути.